# How can I render a 720x480 clip to playback from YouTube in 1080p?

Tags: video, editing, video-quality, youtube, vegas-pro

I'm working on Sony Vegas Pro 14 and I'm editing AMV. The anime clip's resolution that I'm editing is 720x480 - I saw the same clip edited on YouTube and on the settings it was showing that I can watch it in 1080p so I want to know what setting I must use to render that kind of video.

I tried rendering it on 1080p but the effects that I added did not work. I tried to render on 480p widescreen and many more but when I posted it on YouTube it was not showing that I could watch it on 1080p like the other was.

Is there some render setting that I can use to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

This question is not clear at all. Let me explore how many assumptions it has.

> I saw the same clip edited

You are assuming that the other person is using the same clip. He probably had a better resolution one. But here I am assuming the other clip looked better than yours.

He could have just imported a similar resolution clip, let's say extracted from a DVD, and probably it was simply resampled on a FullHD project.

So, no way to respond to that part.

---

But I will answer this:

> 1080p so I want to know what setting I must use to render that kind of video

Prepare a project of the resolution you intent, in this case... 1080p

> I tried rendering it on 1080p but the effects that I added did not work.

Here are again on the realm of "what are we talking about?" What effects?

Again. Simply prepare a project of the intended resolution you want to deliver from the start.

It has two advantages

1. The "effects" or elements will render at the real resolution. If you prepare a project smaller, this simply will produce a blurry or pixelated project.
2. You do not force your equipment making a project bigger. If you prepare a project bigger, your workflow could simply get slower, less fluid.

But if there is a chance you actually need a project bigger at a future time, yes you can prepare it that way and deliver the first version resampled down.